# How to use "as is my" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions

First off,does this sentence make sense-

> I am awaiting my newspaper, as is my morning coffee

What I want to mean is that I and my coffee (personified) are waiting for the newspaper to come. 
Something along the lines of, I am waiting for the newspaper so I can start consuming the coffee, and the coffee(personified) is waiting for the newspaper so it can be consumed by me, before it goes cold.

How else can I word it?

Also I would really appreciate some examples of the usage of "as is my" .

Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Unless the coffee will also read the newspaper, I am not sure that you can personify it in this context without confusing the reader.

Answer (score 3):

It's an unusual construction, since one doesn't normally personify one's coffee, but it does make sense. Indeed, when I first read it I assumed it was a mistake, since it would mean that your coffee was also waiting for your newspaper...but you went on to say that was your meaning.

Other uses of **as is my** might be:

> I'm in need of corrective glasses, **as is my** wife.
>
> I'm working all hours of the day, **as is my** partner.

You can also use it with other words:

> I suffer from an addictive personality, **as does my** son.
>
> I drink a lot of coffee, **as do my** co-workers.
>
> I can eat thirteen bales of hay in a day, **as can my** purple pet elephant.

It doesn't have to be 'my', either:

> Imperial Stormtroopers always miss, **as do** TIE fighter pilots.

In all cases, you're stating a situation or condition that applies to one person or group, then including a second person or group that it applies to.

Comment: Very clear and simple answer that develops the question to cover a few related,  useful constructions.

Comment: Great answer! But then, what if I never gave my explanation, what would you have taken it to mean?
Also a friend of mine was suggesting it doesn't sound right because of subject- object misplacement.
What exactly would you say was wrong, if you hadn't known the meaning I intended?

Comment: @That-Kickass-GirL The only thing that was "wrong" with your example was the personification of your coffee, and that was in fact a perfectly legitimate literary technique. I thought it was a mistake mostly because of the context of this site, where I was *expecting* a mistake. Without your explanation, I likely would have understood it as rather whimsical phrasing, and would probably have read it correctly in context.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction is rare and irregular, and can be misinterpreted as a grammatical error.  To be sure that you convey your intended meaning, you could rewrite it in a much simpler form as

> I and my morning coffee are waiting for the newspaper.
>
> My morning coffee and I are waiting for the newspaper.

The term "as is" (not "as is my") is usually used to mean "also is" without repeating the verb.

> China is a fast growing economic giant,  **as is** India.
>
> My father is highly educated, **as is** my mother.
>
> The belief in evil spirits is much prevalent here,  **as is** the attempt to appease them.
>
> Alcohol is banned within the cinema, **as is** smoking.